# Stop a div from showing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a load more button that appears once the user hits the bottom of the screen / fades out when scrolling up. Like so:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(document).height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
    $("#loadmorebuilds-div").fadeIn();
    } else {
    $("#loadmorebuilds-div").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Here is what I use for loading the new content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageIndex = 1;
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $('#buildcontainer').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=follow&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
           success: function(html) {
              var el = jQuery(html);
              jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
              $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
              pageIndex++;
              $("#buildcontainer").masonry()

              rowCount = $('#countvar').length;
              if (rowCount < 8) {
              window.location.replace("http://localhost/buildsanctuary/index.php");
              }
           }

        });

    });

});
});
```

And this part here, checks the amount of returned data and if its less than requested, it means that there is no more data to show.

```
rowCount = $('#countvar').length;
if (rowCount < 8) {
    window.location.replace("http://localhost/buildsanctuary/index.php");
}
```

The page re-direct is just to test that it was working, what I want is to instead not allow the page to show the load more button again.

How can I go about this?

I tried changing the class e.g.

```
$("#loadmorebuilds-div").attr("class", "loadmorebuild-divhidden");
```

But that doesn't work, the hidden class is just `display:none`.

Thanks.

Comment: `$("#loadmorebuilds-div").hide()`

Comment: but if the user scrolls back up and down again then it is shown again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this by removing it from the dom with

```
.remove()
```

Not sure why i didn't think of this!